# How to automatically append a string to given visited site URLs?

Tags: web-browser, url

I have this site: FOO.COM

Whenever I browse to foo.com, on my local desktop, I need to append a string to the URL manually, for example:

> FOO.COM/barbar?stringhere=true

I want to know how I can do this automatically? The "barbar" in the url, can vary as I browse the website.

Is there a browser add-on, that can help doing this. For Chrome or Firefox?

Then, with the updated URL, the pages shows differently, which is the purpose.